# Route not defined using Laravel MVC PHP Storm

Tags: laravel-5.6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYNes.jpg)

I get this error in PHP storm. I am learning Laravel and can someone please help me with this error. The route is not defined.
Please see the attached screenshot.

Comment: I was surprised I didn't get a response from you on my answer below. I have been using JetBrains for years. I promise you the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 0):

No worries. Php-storm doesn't see some of the laravel facades static classes. (e.g. 'Route::', 'Auth::'). Your code will still run fine (provided there aren't any real problems).

PS - If you haven't done it yet, install the phpstorm laravel plugin. It will help eliminate some of these issues (but not all).

Have fun!